# How to shut down CCC.exe and MOM.exe

Tags: windows-8, amd-catalyst

When I start up my computer(Windows 8), it shows that it's disk usage is 100% (in task manager). It seems that CCC.exe(Catalyst Control Center: Host application) and
MOM.exe(Catalyst Control Center: Monitoring program) causes this. I have googled the question but I still can't find a way to stop these programs to start when I boot up my computer.(If I am not clear enough, just comment on this answer)

Comment: Use something like Autoruns to prevent them from even starting.

Comment: msconfig.exe -- use this on windows search and disable this two processes from startup. Anyway a better solution is to make a program update from Catalyst or a full scan with your antivirus. something is wrong on you system

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this issue on Server 2012R2. In the end, after attempting to just disable the tasks with Autoruns, I ended up using the Catalyst Uninstaller to remove the Catalyst Control Center entirely. This seems to be the only solution to the problem.

As for why the problem exists in the first place, it's anyone's guess. I believe the issue stems from the CCC being dependent on .NET 3.5, which isn't installed by default in Windows 8/8.1 or Server 2012/2012R2. Bizarrely, the installation does not fail if that component is missing on the system. Instead, the application is installed, and it attempts to generate native images of itself, without the necessary pre-requisite .NET version. In the end, the native images that are generated are .NET 4/4.5, and not compatible with the 3.5-based application. This in turn causes the process to hang up and become unstable.

Uninstalling and reinstalling the CCC does not seem to fix this issue either.

Answer (score 0):

Start -> `msconfig` will allow you to disable processes on startup but this doesn't fix the problem. Neither of those processes should be causing 100% disk usage so either they are malfunctioning or your disk is. If those programs are faulty you should remove or replace them, not just cover them up.

Answer (score 0):

I messed around with task manager and I found the programs in "startup". (CCC.exe and MOM.exe) Then I disabled them and that solved the issue.